# get number of repeted weekend period between two dates in JS

Tags: javascript

I have requirement as follows I have two dates i need to find how may given period will come in between

**Date1**: 06-24-2021 18:39:59

**Date2**: 06-27-2021 02:17:03

**Period**: from  thursday 21:00:00 to saturday 05:00:00

Date1 and Date2 just an exemple it could be any

Comment: Did you use a library like 'moment js'

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand the context. is the period is a constant from thursday 21:00:00 to saturday 05:00:00?

Comment: @JabalLogian this period " thursday 21:00:00 to saturday 05:00:00" is an exemple it could be any day of week at specified time to other day at specified time too i mean it's variable

Comment: @AlwaniAnis no i dont use 'moment js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption:** Period(s) we are looking for happens max once per week.

So, basically, you need to find:

1. Starting [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) of the first period between `date1` and `date2` (`start1`)
2. Ending `Date` of the first periodn between `date1` and `date2` (`end1`)
3. Duration of the period (`periodDuration = end1 - start1`)
4. Ending `Date` of the last period between `date1` and `date2` (`finEnd`)
5. Duration of 1 week (`604800000 ms`) (`weekDuration`)
6. `PeriodCount = Math.trunc((finEnd - periodDuration - start1) / weekDuration) + 1`

So in code:

```js
let date1 = new Date("2021-06-24T18:39:59");
let date2 = new Date("2021-06-27T02:17:03");

let start1 = shiftDate(date1, 4, "21:00:00", 1); // start of the first period
let end1 = shiftDate(start1, 6, "05:00:00",1); // end of the first period
let finEnd = shiftDate(date2, 6, "05:00:00", -1); //Notice direction = -1, End of the last period

let periodDuration = end1.getTime() - start1.getTime();
const weekDuration = 604800000; //7 day in miliseconds

let periodCount = 0;
// Check if the first period end time is lower than date2, otherwise there is no full period between the dates
if(end1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
  periodCount = Math.trunc((finEnd.getTime() - periodDuration - start1.getTime()) / weekDuration) + 1 
}

//returns a number of day needed to shift from day to next weekday
//date is Date
//weekday i wanted day index 0 = Sun, ..., 6 = Sat
//time as string "hh:mm:ss" (consider also adding miliseconds "hh:mm:ss:mls" see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours
function shiftDate(date, weekday, time, direction) {
  //direction  1 => shift forward
  //direction -1 => shift backward
  
  let shift = weekday - date.getDay();
  if((direction * shift) < 0){
    shift = shift + direction * 7
  }
  
  let newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + shift); //moves the date by shift (in days)
  newDate.setHours(...time.split(":")); //splits time-string to args
  
  //Check the time, if needed add another week
  if((direction * newDate.getTime()) < (direction * date.getTime())) {
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + direction * 7)
  }
  
  return newDate;
}
```

Comment: this code works well but when i test it with this period
 `2021-07-8T11:52:16 
 2021-07-12T12:54:03 `

it gives me this result 

`start1: null
end1: null
finEnd: "2021-07-10T04:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: I think this is typo in `2021-07-8T11:52:16`, format is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss`, you have olny one digit in day part (`start1` and `end1` is computed from `date1`). Also notice that time in ISO format ending with Z means UTC time. Without Z it's local time. [Source](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/#:~:text=here%E2%80%99s%20what%20the%20values%20mean%3A)

Comment: i am trying to use this script at excel VBA anyone have an idea how to do it

Comment: @Nacer_dz Nope, JS and VBA are too different. But I'm the main idea is very similar and I'm sure there is already some VBA snippet for this.

Answer (score 0):

Converted and tested Excel VBA code

Go to Menu -> Tool -> References -> Microsoft Script Control 1.0 & Enable by Clicking it

```
Dim js As New ScriptControl

Dim Result As Double

Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date

Dim dateTime1 As String, dateTime2 As String
Dim start_weekday As Integer, end_weekday As Integer
Dim start_time As String, end_time As String



dateTime1 = "2021-06-24T18:39:59"
dateTime2 = "2021-06-27T02:17:03"

start_weekday = 4
end_weekday = 6

start_time = "21:00:00"
end_time = "05:00:00"

date1 = DateValue(Split(dateTime1, "T")(0)) + TimeValue(Split(dateTime1, "T")(1))
date2 = DateValue(Split(dateTime2, "T")(0)) + TimeValue(Split(dateTime2, "T")(1))


'Define Scripting Language
' for excel 64bit you must install this msscript.osx  befor use JScript https://tablacus.github.io/scriptcontrol_en.html
js.Language = "JScript"
With js

    'Add JavaScript Code to Script Control Object
    '.AddCode "function shiftDate(date,weekday,time,direction){date=new Date(date);var shift=weekday-date.getDay();if((direction*shift)<0){shift=shift+direction*7}var newDate=new Date(date.getTime());newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+shift);newDate.setHours(time.split(':')[0],time.split(':')[1],time.split(':')[2]);if((direction*newDate.getTime())<(direction*date.getTime())){newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+direction*7)}return newDate}"
    .AddCode "function getWeekend(date1,date2,start_weekday,start_time,end_weekday,end_time)             " & _
    " {                                                                                                  " & _
    "    var start1 =shiftDate(date1,start_weekday,start_time,1);                                        " & _
    "    var end1   =shiftDate(start1,end_weekday,end_time,1);                                           " & _
    "    var finEnd =shiftDate(date2,end_weekday,end_time,-1);                                           " & _
    "    var periodDuration = end1.getTime()-start1.getTime();                                           " & _
    "    var weekDuration = 604800000;                                                                   " & _
    "    var periodCount  = 0;                                                                           " & _
    " if(end1.getTime()<=new Date(date2).getTime())                                                      " & _
    "    {                                                                                               " & _
    "    periodCount=parseInt((finEnd.getTime()-periodDuration-start1.getTime())/weekDuration)+1;        " & _
    "    return periodCount                                                                              " & _
    "    }                                                                                               " & _
    " }                                                                                                  "
    
    
    .AddCode "function shiftDate(date,weekday,time,direction)                                            " & _
    " {                                                                                                  " & _
    " date=new Date(date);                                                                               " & _
    " var shift = weekday-date.getDay();                                                                 " & _
    " if((direction*shift)<0)                                                                            " & _
    "    {                                                                                               " & _
    "    shift = shift+direction*7                                                                       " & _
    "    };                                                                                              " & _
    " var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());                                                            " & _
    " newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+shift);                                                          " & _
    " newDate.setHours(time.split(':')[0],time.split(':')[1],time.split(':')[2]);                        " & _
    " if((direction*newDate.getTime())<(direction*date.getTime()))                                       " & _
    "    {                                                                                               " & _
    "    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+direction*7)                                                  " & _
    "    }                                                                                               " & _
    " return newDate                                                                                     " & _
    " }                                                                                                  "
    

    
     Result = .Run("getWeekend", date1, date2, start_weekday, start_time, end_weekday, end_time)
     Debug.Print Result


End With
```

`